# "could not write to log file, Bad file descriptor" error when working with huge table

Tags: postgresql, restore, windows, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-8.4

I'm having a big problem with a PostreSQL database. Whenever I do something with a huge table (over 9 million rows) the whole postgres process crashes with the following entries in the log file:

```
PANIC:  could not write to log file 000000010000000000000022 at offset 11673600, length 909312: Bad file descriptor
LOG:  WAL writer process (PID 17056) exited with exit code 3
LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
CONTEXT:  COPY fund_records, line 2088885: "..."
LOG:  PID 31820 in cancel request did not match any process
LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
FATAL:  pre-existing shared memory block is still in use
HINT:  Check if there are any old server processes still running, and terminate them.
```

Verbose log information for the "could not write to log file" error from version 8.4.22:

```
XLogWrite, .\src\backend\access\transam\xlog.c:1658
```

The `CONTEXT` is of course differnt depending on what I did. The above `COPY` command was logged when restoring a dump with the big table with pg_restore. Other occurrences were `VACUUM` (when I run vacuum on either the single big table or the whole database) or even `SELECT` (when I run a simple 1 row result select joining the big table).

I can reproduce this crash 100% by either running vacuum on the table or trying to restore the table data from a dump. Sometimes even simple things like selecting from the table or inserting into it cause the crash. It's always the `could not write to log file x at offset y, length z: Bad file descriptor` error. I've already tried disabling autovacuum during pg_resotre but it still fails.

This problem seems to be specific to one server, because the same table/dump works fine when I import it on my local machine. The affected server is a virtual (on Parallels Virtuozzo base) Windows Server 2008 SP2 x64 with 2 GB RAM. There is only a single HDD partition and nearly 40 GB of free space on it. Nothing other than PostgreSQL is running on the server, also no anti virus software. But PostgreSQL is the only application on this server that shows problems, all other operations I've tried work fine, so it seems like it's not a general problem with this machine.

I've tried PostgreSQL server versions 8.4.4 (this was running for years until it first showed the error), 8.4.22 and 9.4.4, all show the same error. I've tried both upgrading from 8.4.4 to 8.4.22 and fresh installs of 8.4.22 and 9.4.4 (there I've also completely deleted the data folder) multiple times. For the upgrade to 9.4.4 I've tried both pg_restore (crashes as already said above) and pg_upgrade. pg_upgrade works, but after that vacuum on the table in 9.4.4 still crashes.

Can someone please explain what's wrong here?

### Update:

I've changed some values in postgresql.conf away from their default values and now the crash happens much rarer. Simple SQL and DML statements don't crash as often any more, but VACUUM still crashes 100%. I'm on version 8.4.22 right now. Here are the values I changed:

```
shared_buffers = 128MB
work_mem = 16MB
maintenance_work_mem = 64MB
wal_buffers = 4MB
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you've actually done a completely fresh PostgreSQL install (with all databases deleted, etc) and restored a dump, then when you try to access this huge table in a freshly restored database you get this error? And you've actually tried *server versions* 8.4 and 9.4? How - copy and pg_upgrade? Dump and restore?

Comment: @CraigRinger Windows event log doesn't show anything when the crash happens. Yes, I've completely uninstalled PostgreSQL and deleted the data folder and then did a fresh install (even tried a different path for both program and data). The crash already happens when I import the table data with pg_restore (table structure and data from all other tables are restored without errors). Yes, I've tried different server versions. I've only tried dump and restore until now, not pg_upgrade (I have a complete server backup where the table data is still in the DB, so I could try it).

Comment: @CraigRinger The original server is the one having the issue. The DB was there for years on version 8.4.4 and suddenly it began crashing. That's when I started trying upgrades and restores. But yes, I can still dump the original server, just restoring/vacuum/maybe something else isn't working (so basically anything that modifies the table data). pg_restore crashes on that server, but does not crash on my Win7 VM (with the same PostgreSQL version and the dump from the crashing server).

Comment: @cremor OK, sounds like there's a high chance that there's a corrupt index then. I'd `REINDEX` if I could afford the interruption. To reduce the impact, do it index-by-index or at least table-by-table, rather than `REINDEX`ing the whole database in one go.

Comment: @CraigRinger But if there is a corrupt index in the dump, why can I restore it on a different machine? I've tried it anyway. REINDEX one by one showed the error "could not fsync segment 0 of relation base/x/y: Bad file descriptor" (manually translated) on an unrelated unique key - but did **not** crash the server. REINDEX on the whole DB showed a similar errror (different x/y) again two times. The third (and all further) REINDEX DB showed no error any more. But even after that, VACUUM still shows the old error and crashes the server.

Comment: @cremor Dumps don't contain the index data,  only an instruction to create them. Also `pg_dump` usually does a sequential scan of the table which will not access the index.

Comment: Does `/proc/user_beancounters` show a non-zero `failcnt`? You might be lacking enough resources for certain operations to finish via settings in Parallels Virtuozzo.

Comment: @Kassandry The server is run by a hosting company. I only have access to my virtual instance. Also, I'm on Windows.

Comment: It sounds like you should bring this up with your hosting company then.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter But how do I convince them that this is their problem? Everything except Postgres works fine. Is there a way to get additional error information from Postgres?

Comment: @cremor: Maybe they have an idea anyway. `Bad file descriptor` sound rather severe to me. Since you have tried both 8.4.22 and 9.4.4, a problem with the underlying OS / file system seems more likely. Aside: I would consider Linux / Unix as OS to run Postgres on.

Comment: I've never found a "real" solution to this problem. But since the server was moved to a new physical host the error doesn't happen any more.